# SQL Exception: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I get an exception"Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed", the function will close resultset every time. Should i add 'synchronized' to the function? or how to solve this exception?

```
        public static ArrayList<Region> getHotProductRegionList() {

            ArrayList<Region> list = new ArrayList<Region>();

            ResultSet rs = null;
            conn.checkConn();
            try {
                    if (getHotProductRegionStmt==null) getHotProductRegionStmt = conn.prepareStatement(getHotProductRegionStr);
                    rs = getHotProductRegionStmt.executeQuery();
                    if (rs!=null) {
                            while (rs.next()) {
                                    Region r = new Region();
                                    setRegion(r, rs);
                                    list.add(r);
                            }
                            rs.close();
                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    J.m("RegionManager.getHotProductRegion Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (rs!=null) try { rs.close(); } catch (Exception ex) {}
            return list;
    }
    private static PreparedStatement getHotProductRegionStmt = null;
    private static String getHotProductRegionStr = " SELECT * FROM Region";
```

And the PreparedStatement reset code:

```
        private static DBConn conn = new DBConn("RegionManager") {
            public void resetAll() {
                    getHotProductRegionStmt = reset(getHotProductRegionStmt);                  
            }
    };
```

Comment: put the last `if (rs!=null)` inside a `finally` block

Comment: thx, but the exception is pointing at "while (rs.next())"

Comment: Stack trace please, in your question. NB The static `PreparedStatement` variable should *certainly* be a local variable, and the `Connection` variable as well.

Comment: The exception occurs all the time ? -- If the connection is closed, do you re-create the prepared statement again ?

Comment: Thx, @Jaime EJP , i updated my post, append PreparedStatement reset code

Comment: But not the stack trace I asked for. Or the actual `reset()` method. Or anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole approach is wrong here. You should be looking to use a new, local, `Connection` and `PreparedStatement` per invocation of this method, and to close them afterwards, and to use a connection pooling to mitigate the effects. Using a static `Connection` is not thread-safe, and using a static `PreparedStatement` is simply never going to work.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to close resultset twice. Instead close the resultset once under finally block.

```
try{ }
catch(Exception e){}
finally{
     if(rs!=null)
           rs.close();
}
```

Comment: private static void setRegion(Region c, ResultSet rs) throws Exception {
                c.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                c.setRegion(rs.getString("region"));
                c.setRegionTw(rs.getString("regionTw"));
          }

Comment: [Calling the method close on a ResultSet object that is already closed is a no-op.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close--), and `rs` cannot possibly be null, and it is *essential* to call `ResultSet.next()` *before* doing anything else with it, such as retrieving values.

Comment: @mav3n thx, but not working.
RegionManager.getHotProductRegion Exception: Before start of result set
java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set